# Fog in Blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

I have a quick question. I started using blender 6 days ago and decided to create car model and animate it. I did and decided to set it in a city scene. All good but i didn't find any good textures for  the skyscrapers and i was hoping of adding some fog to hide it. However i tried everything but no fogs seem to look good enough. It's just a white noisy pixels and it doesn't hide anything. I tried compositing with After Effects too but it didn't work. I did find one clip that can show what i'm trying to do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xjgFJ8zMgA

I'm talking about the last change he makes on the scene. I know it's rendered in cycles but still.. my fog doesn't look like his even in cycles so it's not from the rendering. Does any of you know how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

To get proper fog in EEVEE, surround your scene with a cube, and attach a Volume Scatter node to the Volume output. Make sure no surface is connected. In the image I use below, I multiplied the view distance by a very small number (.00004 - it says 0000 in the pic, but that's just because I used too small a number - it won't even show it until you click the field) to get a very thin fog that increases in strength slightly as it gets farther away.

The camera info and the math node are not necessary, I just find it looks more realistic. If you're not using them, a good value to start with for the volume scatter density would be 0.0015.

Make sure bloom is enabled in the render properties panel. Also, keep in mind that lighting plays a large part of "showing" the fog, so place lights as needed.

[image: FogBox]

[image: FogScene]

EDIT - Don't know if this is closer to what you're looking for, but I'll post it anyway. If you want a more obscuring fog, maybe try a setup like this. You'll probably have to play with the values a little bit to make it fit your scene. Also note that the orange streetlamp color is coming from colored lights I placed in the scene - the fog itself is white.

[image: BetterFog]

Comment: I did use this method i was still not very satisfied with the fog. The Camera Data info is a pretty good idea that i hadn't seen in any tutorials. Next render will definetly include your method in it and i'll see the results i get. However this is still not the desired look i want for my render like the one in the video i linked. Even if it's not done in blender i still wish to know how i can do it. Thanks for the quick response though and the multiply and camera data suggestion, as i said i will use it for sure next time i render my scene.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Can you describe in a bit more detail what it is about the fog in the video you're trying to recreate, but missing? I might be able to do better. You just want to hide the background?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for responding so late. It was like 4AM in my country at the time of the comment. As i said i basically created a car animation in a city but the textures i used for the buildings are not particularly good looking and i was hoping to hide them with some kind of fog or a mist just like the guy in the video has done. So yeah in short, i want to hide the background as much as i can with some kind of fog